# Missing install file, any other way to get it?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2

I've been trying to get my computer to dual boot Windows and Ubuntu for a few days now, and after a lot of troubleshooting and a lot of painful restarts, I've found the error.  I have been using the .iso through a USB, and after scanning the disk for errors and searching through files, 1 file is missing, which I'm assuming is the cause of all my wasted hours reinstalling both OSs:
./pool/main/g/grub2-signed/grub-efi-amd64-signed_1.9~ubuntu12.04.3+1.99-21ubuntu3.9_amd64.deb

Searching through the files on the USB (from the ISO), I found the above directory and confirmed that the file is in fact missing.  I tried redownloading the ISO (from the Ubuntu site), and the same file was missing.  Is there a way to manually retrieve get this file and just drop it into the right place, and would this get the install to work? 
Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

`./pool/main/g/grub2-signed/grub-efi-amd64-signed_1.9~ubuntu12.04.3+1.99-21ubuntu3.9_amd64.deb`

I find that in the iso file

the file name  is: 
`"grub-efi-amd64-signed_1.9~ubuntu12.04.3+1.99-21ubuntu3.9_amd6.deb"`

we wanted:
`"grub-efi-amd64-signed_1.9~ubuntu12.04.3+1.99-21ubuntu3.9_amd64.deb"`